# Why does Narsimha Tapini Upanishad say that Knowledge of Maya leads to liberation?

Tags: scripture, upanishads, brahman, maya, narasimha

[Narasimha Tapini Upanishad states the following](https://upanishads.org.in/otherupanishads/56/3/2) -

> स होवाच प्रजापतिर्माया वा एषा नारसिंही सर्वमिदं सृजति सर्वमिदं रक्षति
> सर्वमिदं संहरति । तस्मान्मायामेतां शक्तिं विद्याद्य **एतां मायां
> शक्तिं वेद स पाप्मानं तरति स मृत्युं तरति स संसारं तरति सोऽमृतत्वं च
> गच्छति महतीं श्रियमश्नुते ॥ २ ॥**
>
> तब प्रजापति ने कहा-नृसिंह भगवान् को सनातनी शक्ति माया के द्वारा ही यह
> संसार रचा गया है, वे ही इसकी रक्षा करती हैं एवं उन्हीं के द्वारा
> सृष्टि का विनाश होता है। इस कारण भगवान् की यह माया ही मंत्रराज की
> शक्ति है। **इस माया को जान लेने पर व्यक्ति पापों से मुक्त हो जाता है,
> मृत्यु पर विजय प्राप्त कर लेता है,अमृतत्व को प्राप्त कर लेता है।
> भवसागर से पार हो जाता है** तथा इस लोक में समस्त प्रकार की समृद्धि
> प्राप्त करता है।।

The Above Says one becomes liberated from Samsāra by the Knowledge of Māyā of Brahman (Who is identified with Narasimha in the text).

My Question is how does it make sense from a Vedanta perspective?

A seeker of Liberation is always directed to seek brahma-jnana... definitely not māyā-jnana! The Scriptures teach that for mumukshus, Maya is fit only to be discarded. Then How can the Knowledge of Maya lead to liberation?